# Bootstrap checkbox & radio lose the style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the codes same as the bootstrap3 sample as below:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
       <input ng-model="user.rememberMe" type="checkbox"> Remember Me
   </label>
</div>
```

and got the style like:

[image]

not like its style in bootstrap sample

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap adds no special styles to a checkbox. We can easily verify this with a live example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

You probably found a theme, fork or non-official example that adds special styles to the checkbox.